# Multiple Plots Instead of One from a Survey Object

Tags: r, plot, survey

I have some problem related with plot a graphic from a survey object, specific a object's class svyimputationList, for plot I use `survey::svyplot()`, combinated with `lodown::scf_MIcombine` - a function based in `mitools::MIcombine` - necessary to imputed the the right variance to the sample. The problem is: the output are a multiple plots and a erro (see below), the code don't condense the lists inside a svyimputationList object in a single plot. Someone have a idea how I solve it?

The code:

```
###Download Data
library(lodown)
scf_cat <-
  get_catalog( "scf" ,
               output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" ) )
scf_cat <- subset( scf_cat , year == 2016 )
scf_cat <- lodown( "scf" , scf_cat )

### Create a survey object
library(survey)
library(mitools)
scf_imp <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , 
                               "SCF" , "scf 2016.rds" ) )
scf_rw <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , 
                              "SCF" , "scf 2016 rw.rds" ) )

scf_design <- 
  svrepdesign( 
    weights = ~wgt , 
    repweights = scf_rw[ , -1 ] , 
    data = imputationList( scf_imp ) , 
    scale = 1 ,
    rscales = rep( 1 / 998 , 999 ) ,
    mse = FALSE ,
    type = "other" ,
    combined.weights = TRUE)

###generate the plot
scf_MIcombine(with(scf_design, svyplot(~debt)))
```

Output:

This separated images:
[image]

```
Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
  no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

**The desired output is a single image, with right take the weights of survey object.**

Comment: What plot do you want this to produce? `MIcombine` isn't going to get you anywhere  -- it's based on means and variances of parameter estimates -- but if you describe what  plot you want someone might be able to say how to make it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I improve the explanation.